# Alternatives to CGI.pm for header() and param()?

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I've been an avid user of [CGI.pm](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) since the previous millennium so I was a bit surprised when it disappeared from my old Ubuntu server when I upgraded it recently.  My short-term fix was `sudo cpan install CGI`, but a quick web search to find out why it was missing in the first place revealed [CGI::Alternatives](http://search.cpan.org/~leejo/CGI-Alternatives-0.14/lib/CGI/Alternatives.pm) which explains why it has gone and offers some suggestions for alternatives.  For my purposes, [HTML::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Tiny/lib/HTML/Tiny.pm) looks best for replacing my programmatic HTML generation, but Alternatives is strangely silent on the subject of HTTP headers and CGI parameters.

I broadened by search and found [lighter alternatives to CGI.pm](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1124719) on perlmonks where one response suggests [CGI::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~szabgab/CGI-Simple-1.115/lib/CGI/Simple.pm), but the recommendation is less than whole-hearted - "its not quite as up to date as CGI.pm".

So is CGI::Simple the way to go, or is there a better alternative?

Please don't spend time suggesting "rewrite everything using framework XXX".  I really don't have the time or energy for that.  I'm happy to replace all my HTML generation with HTML::Tiny, so I'm looking for something with a similar (or lower!) amount of rework to replace header() and param().

Comment: If you need CGI then use CGI. It's not going anywhere any time soon, even though it may no longer be part of core Perl. It's just not a recommended choice for new projects, for the reasons you've already read about. In fact I think you should leave existing HTML-generation the way it is as well, and start using [HTML::Tiny](http://metacpan.org/module/HTML::Tiny)
 or similar on new projects, although it is suffciently similar to the HTML generation capabilities of CGI to be very easily translated

Comment: You may want to check https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/PSGI/PSGI/FAQ.pod#I-have-a-CGI-or-mod_perl-application-that-I-want-to-run-on-PSGI-Plack.-What-should-I-do

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Borodin, but for various reasons I DO want to make the switch to HTML::Tiny for HTML generation for part of my project, so I'm left with the question of what to do about header() and param().  I suppose I could stick with CGI.pm for them, but it seems sensible to make a clean break, so is CGI::Simple up to the job or do I need something different?

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: Apache on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I'm not clear why you want to switch from using `CGI`, especially as you have software that already uses it. You can switch to another PSGI-based framework for new code, but there's no imperative to change what you have already written. As the post you link to says, *“CGI.pm is about as light as it gets, even with all that html stuff you're not using”*

Comment: CGI's HTML-generation is no longer considered good so I want to switch to something cleaner such as HTML::Tiny or another template system.  For example, CGI won't let me add `async` or `defer` attributes to a `<script>` tag for background-loading Google Maps.  Having made the switch for HTML gemeration, should I start using CGI::Simple for param() and header(), should I stick with CGI.pm, or should I use something else?  But I don't want to have to learn a full-blown framework.

Comment: By the way, I like the [`XML::Generator`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Generator) module for this sort of thing. It's happy with either XML or HTML

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, but I really am trying to find out about HTTP headers and CGI parameters, NOT HTML generation.

Comment: @kbro I don't think you're paying attention to what you're being told. If you don't want to use CGI.pm's HTML-generation functions, don't use them. If you want everything else to be exactly the same and you're going to piss on anyone who actually tries to make a suggestion, then just use CGI.pm. No one is holding a gun to your head and making you call its HTML-generation functions.

Comment: That said, `param` is probably the misdesign that has caused the most bugs and security holes in history, and `header` is also really infelicitous.

Comment: @hobbs Clearly importing CGI.pm without using its HTML-generation functions represents *some* amount of wasted effort.  I'm trying to understand *how much* effort that is, and whether using something like CGI::Simple will reduce that overhead.  With the greatest of respect to the suggestors, no amount of "use package xxx for HTML generation" suggestions is going to answer that question. Sorry if my attempts to channel the answers in the direction of the question are causing you offence.

Comment: @kbro no one has suggested that you use any package other than the one you want for HTML generation.

Comment: @hobbs other than the recommendations for PSGI and XML::Generator

Comment: PSGI is not a recommendation to use a different HTML generator. PSGI is a protocol (like CGI) and is entirely agnostic as to how the output is generated.

Comment: So if I want to continue using the CGI protocol to communicate between my web server and my Perl scripts then PSGI is no use whatsoever, because PSGI is a completely different protocol to CGI and will require me to reinstall and/or reconfigure my web server?

Comment: Okay, PSGI/Plack has nothing to do with HTML generation.  What about XML::Generator?

Comment: If [Plack For Beginners](http://savage.net.au/Perl/html/plack.for.beginners.html) is a reasonable description of how to move from Good Ol' CGI to PSGI/Plack then can we agree that it doesn't meet my guidelines for something that requires only a small amount of rework to give me `header` and `param` support?

Comment: PSGI isn't "a completely different protocol to CGI". It's an enhanced version of CGI. It's pretty simple to start moving CGI programs to PSGI. You can even continue running them in a CGI environment.

Comment: Sorry. Misunderstood what you many by "PSGI is a protocols (like CGI)". I took they to mean they're both protocols, but apart from that had nothing in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer to my question is that `use CGI::Simple` is better than `use CGI qw(header param)` because it loads faster.

Answers along the lines of "Use Plack, it's the future of Perl for websites"  weren't helpful to me because I didn't have time to learn a new programming paradigm or to discover how to reconfigure my web server to make it work, no matter how insistent the Plack Evangelists were that I was wrong in what I was trying to do.

I've now had a bit of time to wade through the links to documentation and presentation slides I was offered and I can see what they were getting at, but one failing in what I've read so far is the lack of a concise end-to-end working example to help get my head around things ... so here's what I knocked together to get me started (and, no, I haven't finished yet!).  I hope that others beginning the journey from CGI to PSGI will find this useful to help get them underway...

First you need to install Plack.  I'm running an Ubuntu 14.04 installation so it was simply a matter of running `sudo apt-get install libplack-perl`.  The [generic way](http://plackperl.org) is to install [Task::Plack](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Task-Plack-0.28/lib/Task/Plack.pm) from CPAN.

Next you need to know where your `cgi-bin` directory is located.  You ought to know already if you're a CGI die-hard!  Since I'm running Apache mine is defined in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf` by `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/`.

Now for the magic.  We're going to create a CGI script that runs a PSGI app, handing it data from the CGI environment.  This is good for experimentation and testing but NOT for deployment, as you don't get any of the speed benefit that PSGI can give you (for that you need something like [Plack::Handler::Apache2](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Plack-1.0039/lib/Plack/Handler/Apache2.pm), [Plack::Handler::FCGI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Plack/lib/Plack/Handler/FCGI.pm) or [mod_psgi](https://github.com/spiritloose/mod_psgi/) in Apache, or a dedicated PSGI server such as [Starman](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Starman-0.4014/lib/Starman.pm) or [Starlet](http://search.cpan.org/~kazuho/Starlet-0.16/lib/Starlet.pm), or one of the other handlers mentioned on [PlackPerl.org](http://plackperl.org)).  Create `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/psgi-cgi.pl` with the following contents and make it executable:-

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Plack::Util;
use Plack::Handler::CGI;
my $app = Plack::Util::load_psgi($ENV{PATH_TRANSLATED});
Plack::Handler::CGI->new->run($app);
```

Next we need to tell Apache to pass PSGI app files to this handler.  I did this by creating `/etc/apache2/conf-available/psgi-cgi.conf` containing:-

```
Action psgi-cgi /cgi-bin/psgi-cgi.pl
AddHandler psgi-cgi .psgi
```

then loaded it into my Apache server by running `sudo a2enconf psgi-cgi` and `sudo service apache2 reload`.  Basically you need to get these lines into your `httpd.conf` file and restart the server.

Finally, my first PSGI script, which I created in my server's `DocumentRoot` as `/var/www/html/hello.psgi`:-

```
use Plack::Request;

my $app = sub {
    my $env = shift;
    my $req = Plack::Request->new($env);
    my $par = $req->parameters;

    return [
        200,
        [ 'Content-Type', 'text/plain' ],
        [ "Hello world!\n",
          map("$_ = ".join(", ", $par->get_all($_))."\n", sort keys %$par),
        ]
    ];
};
```

The application is a coderef which returns a 3-element arrayref: the first is the HTTP status code, the second is the name,value pairs for the HTTP header, the third is the body of the response (which could be generated using [HTML::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~andya/HTML-Tiny-1.05/lib/HTML/Tiny.pm) for a web page).  The first 2 elements answer the question of what you need instead of the `CGI::header` function - nothing! (though for more complex handling you'll need [Plack::Response](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Plack-1.0039/lib/Plack/Response.pm)::headers).  The example also shows how to replace `CGI::param` - use [Plack::Request](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Plack-1.0039/lib/Plack/Request.pm)::parameters, which returns a [Hash::MultiValue](http://search.cpan.org/~aristotle/Hash-MultiValue-0.16/lib/Hash/MultiValue.pm) object containing the values of URL (GET) and BODY (POST) parameters, including the ones with multiple values.

Finally, a test:-

```
$ wget -q -O- 'http://localhost/hello.psgi?a=1&a=2&a=3&b=1&b=4'
Hello world!
a = 1, 2, 3
b = 1, 4
```

I hope this is useful to other CGI die-hards in taking their first steps towards PSGI proficiency, and I hope the Plack Evangelists will acknowledge that it takes a lot of reading and comprehension to get even this far.

Comment: You can avoid the need for your `psgi-cgi.pl` by simply writing your `hello.psgi` and giving it a shebang line of `#/usr/bin/plackup`.

Comment: @DaveCross how do you configure Apache in this case?

Comment: If your Apache already runs CGI programs, then no more configuration is needed. Just drop your PSGI programs into the existing cgi-bin directory.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the point if you're looking for an alternative that provides `header` and `param`.

The argument for the removal of CGI.pm from core (but not from CPAN) is that you shouldn't have to deal with CGI yourself; you should be using a framework that handles this for you.

If you don't agree with this — if you're looking for an equivalent to `header` and `param` — go ahead and keep using CGI.pm.

If you do agree, CGI::Simple is no better than CGI.pm.

Comment: ??? I am looking for an alternative to CGI.pm for header() and param().  That's why the title of my question is "Alternatives to CGI.pm for header() and param()?"

Comment: And I explained that the question makes no sense. If you want something like `header` and `param`, just keep using CGI.pm

Comment: CGI::Simple also provides `header` and `param`, so should I use that in preference to plain old CGI?  If so, why?  If not, why not?  Do other modules also provide `header` and `param` as roughly drop-in replacements?  If so, which ones, and what are the pros and cons of using them over either CGI::Simple or plain old CGI?

Comment: The fact that CGI.pm was removed from core is not a reason to switch from CGI to CGI::Simple. Switch if you want, but it has nothing to do with the issue you identified in your question.

Comment: From the [POD](http://search.cpan.org/~szabgab/CGI-Simple-1.115/lib/CGI/Simple.pm) for CGI::Simple: "In practical testing this module loads and runs about twice as fast as CGI.pm depending on the precise task."  This looks like a very good reason for switching to CGI::Simple.  Why do you think I should stay with CGI.pm?

Comment: Because I have to stay on topic.

Comment: The topic in my question is "So is CGI::Simple the way to go, or is there a better alternative?".  So what makes CGI.pm a better alternative?

Comment: Again, It's not that CGI.pm is better, it's that CGI::Simple is just as bad as CGI for the reason for switching you gave. P5P: "Caffeine is bad for you, so we're going to stop enabling coffee-drinkers." kbro: "Oh, should I switch to Coke?" ikegami: "No, that won't help."

Comment: Okay, to put things in terms that you'll understand... I want to carry on eating burgers (using the CGI protocol) even though I know they're bad for me (PSGI is available).  Do I go for high-fat burgers (CGI.pm) or low-fat burgers (CGI::Simple).

Comment: Comments are not the place to ask questions. For starters, they lead to very poor questions such as that one. (You didn't specify a criteria by which to evaluate which is better for you.)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, there's no reason not to use CGI together with HTML::Tiny. So that's the answer to your question. For the last five years that I was using CGI, my programs all started something like:

```
use CGI qw[param header];
```

which is the approach you're talking about here.

If you wait a year or two, the plan is for the HTML generation functions to be removed from the main module, so your problems will all go away at that point.

But that's not what I'd do in your situation. I'd switch to using [PSGI](https://metacpan.org/release/PSGI) and [Plack](https://metacpan.org/release/Plack). You said that you don't want anyone to suggest a new framework, so I'm not going to do that. Plack isn't a framework, it's a toolbox for writing PSGI applications. Certainly, I'd use a framework like Dancer, but you don't have to. You can happily use Plack without any of the frameworks built on top of it.

You'll still get most of the advantages of PSGI. You'll be able to deploy your applications in any way you like. You'll have access to all the awesome Plack middleware. Testing your program will be far easier.

When you're using "raw" Plack, the equivalent of `CGI::param` is `Plack::Request::parameters` and the equivalent of `CGI::header` is `Plack::Response::headers`.

So there are three answers to your question.

1. Carry on using CGI.pm. Just stop using the HTML generation functions and replace them with HTML::Tiny
2. Use raw PSGI/Plack and bring your web development into the 21st century
3. Use one of Perl's many great web frameworks.

Unfortunately, you don't seem to like any of those answers.

Comment: On the contrary! Thank you for your clear explanations.  So CGI using just param and header doesn't give me a huge code bloat overhead compared to CGI::Simple, and I guess it means I can still use CGI's `<input>` tag magic for sticky forms - at least until the HTML generation cruft is removed.  On the subect of PSGI/Plack, the answer "you may want to check ...PSGI" was too vague to be helpful whereas your instructions on how to use "raw" Plack are spot on.

Comment: These slides on [Modern Web Development with Perl](http://www.slideshare.net/davorg/modern-web-development-with-perl) might be useful in getting to grips with PSGI and Plack.

Comment: one thing your answer doesn't cover is a comparison between CGI.pm and CGI::Simple for param/header handing.  CGI::Simple claims to be just as good a CGI.pm in this respect, and also claims to load and run twice as fast, so given that I don't want to jump to PSGI/Plack this week, why would I not choose to go with CGI::Simple?  What made you choose to stay with CGI.pm rather than make that switch?

Comment: I didn't comment on CGI::Simple as I know nothing about it. Switching to use just the bits of CGI.pm that I wanted made sense to me. If you're worried about performance, then CGI is the wrong web application environment for you :-) Having investigated further though, I see that CGI::Simple and HTML::Tiny were both written by the same person - so I'd be surprised if they didn't work well together.

Comment: I have to say I'm impressed with HTML::Tiny even though I've only used it for about 4 hours.  The reference-to-nested-tag mechanism lets you generate some complex structures very elegantly. I hadn't noticed that it shares an author with CGI::Simple.  That makes me more confident in using that package until I have time to follow the majority recommendation and switch away from CGI altogether.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with CGI.pm is not that it's going away, merely that it will no longer be distributed as part of the core Perl distribution.  However that doesn't mean you have to install from CPAN.  On your Ubuntu system you can just do:

```
sudo apt-get install libcgi-pm-perl
```

and you'll be off and running with the same old CGI you know and love :-)

Comment: Removal from Core Perl isn't the only issue with CGI.pm.  I'm being steered towards HTML::Tidy and I happy to go that way, I just want to know what to use for header() and para() - CGI::Simple or something else.

Comment: Oh sure, using the HTML-generation methods that CGI.pm provided was always a terrible idea :-) Just use `param` and `header` from CGI.pm and ignore the rest.

Comment: Which is why I want to use HTML::Tiny. And if I do that, will CGI::Simple give me the other stuff I'd lose by abandoning CGI.pm?

Comment: Really CGI.pm is awful code (remember it was written when the web was a new thing and has huge swathes of backcompat and x-platform cruft).  The alternatives like CGI::Simple are a bit better, but really you want to replace it with something like Dancer2 or heavier weight alternatives like Catalyst and Mojo.  You can always code direct to Plack::Request and Plack::Response for simple stuff.  Your existing CGI scripts will however continue to work.

Comment: @singingfish no argument that writing new code to the CGI.pm API would be crazy (and I also would recommend Dancer2), but if you have an existing CGI script that doesn't work simply because CGI.pm is no longer bundled with Perl, then just installing the CGI package is the most sane solution.

Answer (score -1):

[CGI::Minimal](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI%3A%3AMinimal) would a good option, it is much lighter than CGI & CGI::Simple, but it lacks advanced methods like CGI & CGI::Simple